# How to get my jQuery UI "close" button to show up in the upper right of the DIV and not impede the flow of text?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

As you can see from the demo, I have two divs, `notice` and `content`:

**http://jsfiddle.net/ssZXA/**

`notice` is for error messages that occasionally need to be displayed while `content` is for the main page content that is always present.

I created a button (`closebutton`) that causes the `notice` section to disappear.

But I don't know how to position it in the upper right area of the `notice` div - where you would expect a close button to be - without interfering with the flow of text.

Answer (score 2):

Place the button before the text and add this CSS:

```
#closeButton{
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do it like this:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ssZXA/3/

```
#notice {
    position: relative
}
#closebutton {
    position: absolute;
    top: -14px; right: -14px;
    width: 28px; height: 28px
}
```

You could do it without the `-14px`, but then it would look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ssZXA/4/ (which is no good because the text overlaps).

In that case, you'd be better going with one of the `float: right`-based answers. Or a smaller button.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

One is getting the button before the text (inside the `div`) like that:

```
    <button id="closebutton" style="display: inline; float: right">Close</button>
```

The other is getting a `div` on the top and the getting the button code above.

The difference between them is that in the first on, the text will co-exist with the button in the same area. In the second one, the div above will create an empty area, because the button will have floated to the right.

Answer (score 1):

im no expert in css but check this out 
http://jsfiddle.net/sharan/ssZXA/1/

small button
http://jsfiddle.net/sharan/ssZXA/2/